# SSH error setting file in comand line windows

Tags: ssh

C:\Users\User>ssh-add C:\Users\User.ssh\id_rsa_do
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory

Identity added: .ssh\id_rsa_do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you missing a "\" in the file name?

Should it be C:\Users\User\.ssh\id_rsa_do   ( a backslash before the .ssh ) ?

Once you have the key installed, you have to tell ssh to use it when you try to connect to the remote server

`ssh -i C:\Users\User\.ssh\id_rsa_do root@142.93.107.127`

Comment: no i rewrote with '\' but the same error

Comment: i had firstly such kind of problem:

Comment: root@142.93.107.127: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: if you're seeing this message, it tends to imply that the key has been added : Identity added: .ssh\id_rsa_do

Comment: ok, and how i can look into the root@142.93.107.127

Comment: C:\Users\User>ssh root@142.93.107.127
root@142.93.107.127: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: try `ssh -i C:\Users\User\.ssh\id_rsa_do root@142.93.107.127`

Comment: can you help me once more?

Comment: C:\Users\User>ssh djangoadmin@142.93.107.127
djangoadmin@142.93.107.127: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: try that again but with the -i flag

Comment: I tried but error still exists

Comment: when i added new user. i cant login as new user.